# How can I right-align a cell in a Wicket table column?

Tags: datatable, wicket

I'd like to have a `PropertyColumn` of a `DataTable` right-aligned. But if I try to add a `new SimpleAttributeModifier("align", "right")` to the cell item, it is added to a `span` within the `td`, rather than the `td` itself.

```
public class AssetSizeColumn<T> extends PropertyColumn<T> {
...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, String componentId, IModel<T> rowModel) {
    IModel<Long> model = (IModel<Long>) createLabelModel(rowModel);
    Component label = new Label(componentId, model.getValue().toString());
    label.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("align", "right"));
    item.add(label);
}
```

Can I get at the `td` to set the alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the `td` is the parent of the item as soon as it is added to the `ICellPopulator`, so that we can add a modifier to it straight away.

```
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, String componentId, IModel<T> rowModel) {
    IModel<Long> model = (IModel<Long>) createLabelModel(rowModel);
    Component label = new Label(componentId, model.getObject().toString());
    item.add(label);
    label.getParent().add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("align", "right"));
}
```